# How to update the state value's key dynamically in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

My state values are

```
this.state = {
    str: {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2",
    }
}
```

`key` and `value` are setting dynamically. If i change the `key` that is setting dynamically from a text box value, How can I update the `key` in the state?

My handle function is

```
handleChange(e) {
    const name = "key1a"
    const value = "value1"
    if(this.state.str.hasOwnProperty("key1") {
        /* I want to change the key1 to key1a here! */
    }
}
```

My required state values should be

```
this.state = {
    str: {
        key1a: "value1",
        key2: "value2",
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you tell which object property you want to change? ie: `key1` and not `key2`

Comment: That I'm getting from other values. And not mentioned in detailed here. I'm just mentioning the functionality required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you could go about doing that using the simpler route of using object destructuring,

```
    handleChange(e) {
      const name = 'key1a';
      const value = 'value1';
      if (this.state.str.hasOwnProperty("key1")) {
        const { ["key1"]: replaceKey, ...other } = this.state.str;
        this.setState({
          str: {
            ...other,
            [name]: value
          },
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination or `Object.entires()` and `.reduce()` to find the key you want to change and retain its value for the new state-object.

```
handleChange(e) {
    const { str } = this.state
    const name = "key1a"
    const value = "value1"
    const allPairssWithoutKey1 = null


    if(this.state.str.hasOwnProperty("key1") {
       allPairssWithoutKey1 = Object.entries(str).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
           if(key !== "key1"){
              acc[key] = value
           } else {
              acc[name] = value
           }
           return acc
       }, {})
    }

    this.setState({
       str: allPairssWithoutKey1 
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleChange(e) {
  const keyIWantReplaced = "key1";
  const keyIWantToReplaceWith = "key1a";

  let str = { ...this.state.str }; //Shallow copying the object to avoid reference issues
  let key1Value = str[keyIWantToReplace];
  delete str[keyIWantToReplace];
  str[keyIWantToReplace] = key1Value;
  this.state({
    str
  });
}
```